# JsHttpRequest and IE notification about ActiveX

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer

The use of `JsHttpRequest` for data transfering leads to IE notification about ActiveX.

• Are there any ways to circumvent this?

• Or are there any alternative ways of transfering data without page reloading, that do not lead to the appearance of this message?